# Play multiple audios on Ipad or touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

How to play multiple audio on ipad at same time
i have tried following code but it doe not plays multiple audio

```
<audio id="audioId" src="music.mp3">Play audio</audio>
<audio id="audioId1" src="intro.mp3">Play audio</audio>
 <script>
  document.getElementById("audioId").play();
  document.getElementById("audioId1").play();
 </script>
```

The above code does not play both audios on IPAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require click or touch to play audio on touch device 
you can play multiple audios on device using following code

```
  <div id="btn">Play Double sound</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#btn").on("click",function(){
                        alert("audio clicked");
                        var aud=new Audio();
                        aud.src="music.mp3";
                        aud.play();
                        var aud1=new Audio();
                        aud1.src="intro.mp3";
                        aud1.play();
                    })
        });

    </script>
```

The above code plays multiple audios on touch devices